# How can I add custom HTML attributes to an ASP.NET label without code-behind access?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, server-side, serverside-javascript

I am making some modifications to a website, but it is hosted by a third party so I don't have code-behind access, how can I add custom HTML attributes (Rich Snippets) to an ASP label or other element?

Code:
`<asp:Label ID="lblPositionTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>`

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have access to the ASPX and ASHX files but no code-behind files, because it is a system used for 800 other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPositionTitle" runat="server" richAttribute="value"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `jquery` available?
... just add the attribute like:

```
<script> 

$("#<%=lblPositionTitle.ClientID%>").attr("newAttributeName", "theValue"); 

</script>
```

Comment: Just wondering, can this or something similar be run server-side?

Comment: Sure, there's an attributes property for your server controls.

Answer (score 0):

Is using HTML5, you can use the data-* attribute:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp